# Errors with importing TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, runtime-error, anaconda

Supposedly I had installed correctly TensorFlow through Anaconda, and I activated TensorFlow successfully by typing (in Anaconda prompt):

```
C:> activate tensorflow
```

But when I try to validate it (also, in Anaconda prompt) by

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get two errors:

```
**ImportError: DLL load failed with the error code -1073741795**
```

and

```
**ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'**
```

finally, it adds:

```
Failed to load the native Tensorflow runtime
```

Also, in the tutorial are specified (for validating the installation) the next steps:

*Start a terminal.*

*If you installed through Anaconda, activate your Anaconda environment.*

*Invoke python from your shell as follows:*

*$ python*

...

So, I've considered that I could have missed the "activate Anaconda environment", since I simply made the next:

```
C:\Users\username> activate tensorflow
(tensorflow) C:\Users\username>python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

But then, what does it mean to **activate Anaconda environment**?

What could I have missed?

**Edit:**

I've tried to see if I get any more information of the error by trying to run the next .py file in Pycharm (being the interpreter `C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe`)

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

When I try to run it, I get similar TensorFlow error, whose trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/PycharmProjects/mnist-trainer/MNISTTrainer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 577, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 938, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Edit2:**

Since the error seems to be related to the TensorFlow version, I've followed this tutorial:

```
https://pathtogeek.com/installing-tensorflow-on-window-with-pycharm-ide
```

So, I've created a conda variable named "tensorflownew" from Pycharm. Then, in the Anaconda Prompt, I could succesfully activate the "tensorflownew" variable. 
But when I use the...

```
(tensorflownew) C:\>pip install –ignore-installed –upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

...the command doesn't execute. Instead, I get a "Usage" command list and a strange message:

```
no such option: -u
```

I don't understand what does it mean with "-u". Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Which type of tensorflow you've installed, with or without GPU support? [This answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11571#issuecomment-316126312) provides a script which may help you identify missing DLLs.

Comment: I've installed it with CPU support only, not with GPU support

Comment: This could be a difficult problem to troubleshoot. Check [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386) for potential fix. According to that, one best guess is your CPU lack AVX instruction. Maybe start with checking your CPU?

Comment: You can try `pip install --ignore-installed tensorflow==1.4.0`. If AVX instruction is indeed your problem, I would suggest give [fo40225's wheel](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386#issuecomment-370129452) a try.

Comment: Thank you, but when trying to install a lower TensorFlow version (as the issue shows that could be a solution), I get a strange error (see Edit2).

Comment: If you run `pip install -h`, you will see all options and I believe your pip will be the same which has double dash for both `--ignore-installed` and `--upgrade`.

Comment: Ok. The command you gave me in your second comment was correct! I typed it in the console and TensorFlow installed without problems. In addition, the validation test was successful. Thank you!

Comment: I would make another suggestion. Why don't you give your own answer with all details including your CPU status, tensorflow type, solution(s) you've tried and/or worked, etc. It will make this question useful for others in the future.